# WebStorm can't recognize live.json as json file

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

WebStorm doesn't apply json format/color highlight for json file when it named `live.json`, any other name works just fine.

I am using WebStorm 2016.2.4 Build #WS-162.2228.20, built on October 18, 2016

Any advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check Settings | Editor | File Types, look for the file type that has "live.json" associated with it (most likely this will be "Text") and remove the association.